# "Error when calling the metaclass bases" when declaring class inside a module

Tags: python

Let me start by saying, I also get the same error whey defining `__init__` and running `super()`'s `__init__`. I only simplified it down to this custom method to see if the error still happened.

```
import HTMLParser

class Spider(HTMLParser):
    """
    Just a subclass.
    """
```

This alone in a module raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\my\path\to\my\file
    class Spider(HTMLParser):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: There shout be a definnetly better debug message.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

And the answer is that I'm a complete noob. This is a module, not a class, but I'll leave this up here in case other noobs run into the same problem.

Solution:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
```

Each time I think I'm starting to become a pro, something like this happens :(

Comment: I don't know, I could actually see this tripping up a lot of people, having the module and the class within the module named the same.

Comment: I think there's a quite a range of existence between `complete noob` and `pro`.

Comment: (deleted a set of comments with multiple flags from multiple users; off-topic to the question)

Comment: I do this sort of thing with modules like `StringIO` and `timeit` all the time.  And `datetime`.  Don't get me started on `datetime`.